# Cron job and shell script to split string and send to SparkCore?

Tags: shell, sed, cron, sparkcore

I'd like to use [selfspy](https://github.com/gurgeh/selfspy) to track clicks, keystrokes and mouse movements, and then use a cron job to run a shell script and split the string using (I believe) `sed` and send the information via `curl` to a SparkCore. Can anyone help me with the `sed` portion of this?

The bash command `selfstats --clicks` returns this:

```
$ selfstats --clicks
5006 keystrokes in 407 key sequences, 2791 clicks (2361 excluding scroll), 157648 mouse movements

Mouse clicks:
2298 left
0 middle
26 right
143 up
287 down
```

What I want on the SparkCore side is:

```
clicks = 2791;
keystrokes = 5006;
mouseMovement = 157648;
```

So far I think the shell script would look something like this, with the correct `sed` commands:

```
# !/bin/bash

CLICKS="$(selfstats --clicks | sed)"
KEYSTROKES="$(selfstats --clicks | sed)"
MOUSE_MOVEMENT="$(selfstats --clicks | sed)"

curl https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/0123456789abcdef/programname \
    -d access_token=123412341234 -d clicks=$CLICKS

curl https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/0123456789abcdef/programname \
    -d access_token=123412341234 -d keystrokes=$KEYSTROKES

curl https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/0123456789abcdef/programname \
    -d access_token=123412341234 -d mouseMovement=$MOUSE_MOVEMENT
```

Comment: Okay, well I used `selfstats --clicks | sed '2,9d' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'` which returned keystokres, `5006`, so that seemed successful. I would imagine there is a more concise way to do this, but I can't get there. And, I thought RE stores up to 9 patterns, and that I would be able to chance the command to `selfstats --clicks | sed '2,9d' | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\3/'`, but this did not work: `sed: 1: "s/\([0-9]*\).*/\3/": \3 not defined in the RE`.

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly parsing the same string is wasteful and frustrating. It would be best if the tool you use could produce machine-readable output, but if its output format is reasonably static, you could do

```
selfstats --clicks |
awk '{print $1,$7, $12 }' |
while read -r keystrokes clicks mousemovement; do
    :
done
```

In Bash, you could do

```
read -r keystrokes clicks mousemovement <(selfstats --clicks |
awk '{print $1,$7, $12 }')
```

You should prefer lowercase variable names both to give your eyes some rest and because uppercase is reserved for the shell's internal use.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I couldn't quite get what you posted to work, but the awk addition was very helpful. The shell script looks like this:

```
# !/bin/bash

activity="$(selfstats --clicks | sed '2,9d' | awk '{print $1,$7, $12 }')"

curl --silent https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/0123456789abcdef/echo \
  -d access_token=123412341234 -d "args=$activity"
```

So, this works perfectly when I run it directly from terminal and check the serial monitor, giving the three variables: `5006 2791 157648`, which I can split on the Spark Core side. But, when I run the job as a cron job, the serial monitor just displays a line break. Any ideas?

Comment: Hm... can you try logging your output from the cronjob to a file to make sure that it is outputting correctly. Just log the results of the curl command or something with append `echo $results > output.log`, let your cronjob run a few times, and then check `output.log` to make sure that it is behaving as you had hoped. P.S. you might want to remove your `access_token` from this stackoverflow question.